# Append data frame in R to new columns

Tags: r

Here is an example of sample data frames

data.frame1

```
col1  col2 col3 col4 
1     2    3    4
2     3    4    4
```

data.frame2

```
col5  col6 col7 col8
 1    2    3     4
 3    3    5     9
```

data.frame3

```
col9  col10  col11  
1      2     3
```

Desired output 
data.frame.append

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 
1     2    3    4    NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
2     3    4    4    NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
NA   NA    NA   NA   1    2    3   4    NA   NA    NA
NA   NA    NA   NA   3    3    5   9    NA   NA    NA
NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA   1    2     3
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this that scales to any number of data frames created on the fly.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Thank you all; and efficiency is of your interest, brief discussion can be found [here](https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/09/a-speed-test-comparison-of-plyr-data-table-and-dplyr/)

Comment: In terms of efficiency, `data.table::rbindlist` would be faster.

Comment: imho this question is not a duplicate - the other question is not about efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this with `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
#    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11
#1    1    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
#2    2    3    4    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
#3   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2    3    4   NA    NA    NA
#4   NA   NA   NA   NA    3    3    5    9   NA    NA    NA
#5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1     2     3
```

Answer (score 6):

The easier way is to use `plyr::ldply`:

```
ldply(list(df1, df2, df3))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11
1    1    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
2    2    3    4    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
3   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2    3    4   NA    NA    NA
4   NA   NA   NA   NA    3    3    5    9   NA    NA    NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1     2     3
```

Comment: Easier than...?

Comment: Adam, I have added an image of input and output in pseudo format. Perhaps it gives you a clear picture of what I am after. I could see that your code has generated mean, however I was not able to integrate that into produce my final output data frame.